# Edit Custom View's Canvas Without Calling OnDraw?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-canvas, ondraw, invalidation

I'm making a graphing library in Android and am aware that if I update the canvas by calling invalidate it can cause a heap memory problem in some devices especially when the user is using a `Relative Layout` and has some views loading or has multiple graphs stacked on each other. So what I want to do is change the graph of the view without android having to redraw all other views on the Relative Layout.

The only solution I have come across is adding a boolean system to the custom view's on draw to check if the same view requested the on draw, otherwise it would keep the same canvas. However, this will only prevent the same view from being redrawn again and will also draw the other views when it is drawn.

Here is the solution mentioned above.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(cropx != 0){
    croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawGraph2, 0, 0, (drawGraph2.getWidth()*cropx/100), drawGraph2.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(croppedBmp, 0, 0, new Paint());
    croppedBmp.recycle();
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    }
    status = false;
}
public void plotPoints(ArrayList<Double> yvalue, ArrayList<Double> xpoint){
    drawpath2 = new Path();
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(drawGraph2);
    drawCanvas.scale(1, -1);
    boolean first = false;
    for(int i = 0; i< xpoint.size(); i++){
     if(!Double.isNaN(yvalue.get(i))){
        if(first == false){
    drawpath2.moveTo(xpoint.get(i).floatValue(),yvalue.get(i).floatValue());
    first = true;
    }else if(i==xpoint.size()-1){
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawpath2, paint);
        drawpath2.reset();
    }else{ 
    drawpath2.lineTo(xpoint.get(i).floatValue(), yvalue.get(i).floatValue());
    }
     }
    }
    Canvas singleUseCanvas = new Canvas(drawGraph2);  
    singleUseCanvas.drawPath(drawpath, paint);
    status = true;
    invalidate();
}
```

Comment: no wonder that you have heap memory problems if you use Bitmap.createBitmap in onDraw method

Comment: What would you recommend me doing? How can create the Bitmap before and draw on it on the Canvas in the OnDraw?

Comment: what do you need that Bitmap for?

Comment: so why not canvas.drawPath() in onDraw? this is the normal way of drawing the path

Comment: Wouldn't I need a Canvas with a bitmap to draw onto? Also how would I state the Canvas size without the bitmap in the Canvas to draw onto? I thought I needed the bitmap to specify the dimensions. Well anyways I'm drawing onto it from another method and that exact canvas isn't available there. I guess I can make the path a global variable and access it from the onDraw. The problem is I also have other methods such as drawing the axis so I would have to set up more conditions in the onDraw?

Comment: yes the only place you use Canvas.draw* is onDraw merhod - the exception  is when you want to draw on Bitmap's canvas (to be later used in several places), but normal drawing should only be made in onDraw method

Comment: So would you recommend having a predawn bitmap before calling the onDraw or passing the information to be drawn in the on draw using a global variable?

Comment: More specifically by passing information I mean the points to be plotted directly on the views canvas in the on draw. I guess one good think about passing them to the onDraw would avoid using a bitmap but it might result in more code in the on draw and a less neat method since most of the work would be happening in the onDraw and I would have to check if it was drawn from that method so it won't be drawn again just in case it was invalidated from outside. Also can I make another canvas outside the on draw that I can copy in the on draw?

Comment: option #2 for sure, i mentioned drawing on Birmap just as an example when you use that Bitmap not as the whole canvas rwplacemwnt but rarher a small set of pixels to be used later on in several places of onDraw method

Comment: Alright thanks I guess ill do that then. With a bitmap it doesn't have to be recreated every time it can be drawn once as a global variable and set every time to the canvas.  But I'm going to avoid the bitmap route for sure and go with drawing directly on the canvas and will manage all the situations from the onDraw meathead itself.